# iOS Swift game wrong orientation

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, screen-orientation

I am trying to make an iOS game (Swift, SpriteKit) that can only be played in portrait orientation. The problem I have is that even though the app loads in portrait and cannot be rotated, according to the frame size, my app thinks it's in landscape. So the app is in portrait, but I get "Height: 768, Width: 1024".

This is the usual code for rotation that I have in my app:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.toRaw())
}
```

And every place in the app that asks for device orientation I've put to Portrait (Info.plist file, Main.storyboard etc...). I googled this and found some solution from about a year ago where you put "viewWillLayoutSubviews()" instead of the usual "viewDidLoad" method, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone else has this issue and can anyone please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: select the target of your project and just check the portrait option and inside storyboard open file inspector and uncheck the Use Size Classes option and now your game should have the iphone screen size and your game should run in portrait

Comment: No, that's not it. It still prints out that the width is 1024 and height is 768

Comment: There is a related post here worth looking at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219616/ipad-shows-at-portrait-but-thinks-its-landscape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out what was wrong. The size of the Scene in the GameScene.sks file needs to be set to portrait resolution and after that you need to save it (cmd+S). If you don't save it and you just build it instead, the screen size in the file will show the portrait resolution that you typed in but it will remember the previous resolution and still act as a landscape app even though the device orientation is portrait.